# Does the protection of Legal Privilege apply to encrypted documents?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, common-law, attorney-client-privilege, encryption

My understanding, based upon Common Law in England & Wales, is once something is sent to a solicitor, it is subject to Legal Privilege.

If the solicitor is unable to open an emailed document, say because it is password protected with an unknown password, would the contents still be subject to Legal Privilege without being seen?

If the solicitor refused to store it on their email server, because it was unreadable, and they deleted the email, would it still have Legal Privilege?

For this question, assume that the sender knows the password and is happy to provide it at a future date, when they want their solicitor to view the document.

Comment: If the solicitor never read the document and deleted it, then it doesn't matter whether it has legal privilege.  If the solicitor can't produce something, then there is likewise nothing for the privilege to protect.

Comment: @phoog What if I show my sent folder on Hotmail and prove I sent the document that the solicitor deleted?

Comment: That just shows that you sent it, if they don't have it they don't have it.  So, what if what?

Comment: @MichaelHall I can somehow prove I sent this to my solicitor, even though he never received it because *insert internet related catastrophe here* or because the solicitor deleted it without even looking.

Comment: Yes, you can prove you sent it.  What does that have to do with legal privilege?

Comment: @MichaelHall If I can prove I sent it, but the solicitor never received it, is it protected by Legal Privilege?

Comment: Yes..  it is.  But what does that matter in practical terms?

Comment: @MichaelHall I was worried that if by an accent the email never reached the solicitor due to computer malfunction, then any law enforcement official would have free reign over it... But now you have clarified I have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the electronic bytes of the attachment that has privileged status, it is the communication between attorney and client - i.e. the information and ideas contained within the document.

If an encoded document is not human readable, and/or it is subsequently deleted, then there has been no communication - no exchange of information between attorney and client.  There would be no conversation, no statements, no evidence, opinions or legal strategy shared, no compelled testimony as to the (unknown) contents... in other words there is nothing to protect.

Note, however, that the attachment and its contents should be presumed to contain privileged information, and be treated in the same manner as an unopened letter.  In other words, it should be safeguarded by the same means as any other attorney client communication under the assumption that a password will be provided later.

Comment: What would happen if the solicitor was requested (under some law) to provide this attachment, BEFORE the solicitor is given the password to be able to read it? My thinking is that before they are given the password, they have not read it, so no Legal Privilege protection exists...?

Comment: That's an interesting question. Most such requests, or requirements, are for a specific thing, and that thing would be clearly specified. (for example, phone records, DNA results, a photograph or video...) Without even knowing with the file contains how might a solicitor comply? Conversely, if any and all client/attorney communication, (including email) falls under legal privilege, why would anyone ever presume that an attachment, encrypted or not, might NOT qualify?!

Comment: @user5623335 It would almost surely be privileged subject to exceptions to the privilege (most notably the crime-fraud exception).

Comment: @user5623335 It would be protected - just like an unopened letter would be.

Comment: @DaleM, the unopened letter is a geat example.  I may edit this into my answer ...

Comment: So you're saying the encrypted document itself would be protected by Legal Privilege, but not the decrypted contents since the password has not been provided? Then what about the unopened letter example given by Dale M?

Comment: @ohwilleke I should clarify, the document is completely legal, nothing malicious etc... it is perhaps evidence I want the solicitor to hold onto, maybe a step-by-step recount of events, basically something completely benign.

Comment: @user5623335 I wouldn't expect otherwise, but just wanted to clearly state the rule.

Comment: "*So you're saying the encrypted document itself would be protected by Legal Privilege, but not the decrypted contents...*"  I am actually saying the exact opposite.  In any case, I made a few slight edits, please let me know if that clarifies anything.

Comment: @MichaelHall Just looking at the last paragraph in your updated answer, I understand it should be treated in the same way as a client-attorney communication. However, whilst it might be treated that way, the question remains: is it protected by Legal Privilege? For example, if the police wanted a copy of it (or whatever example your mind wants to invent), could that be prevented by virtue of the fact it was emailed to a solicitor so is now subject to Legal Privilege?

Comment: It is presumed to be privileged communication, so yes.

Comment: @MichaelHall Perfect, so when an attachment is sent to a solicitor's email address, whether or not they can open it due to encryption, it is subject to Legal Privilege. Please clarify that in a sentence at the end of your answer so I can mark it as answered. Thank you so much! P.S There is a bounty on this question, easy points if you clarify an answer: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/95165/dual-criminality-with-an-mlat

Comment: What about my last paragraph is unclear?  It sounds like you are asking for a "ruling" or something absolute based on case law dealing with this specific scenario, neither of which I am qualified to provide.

Comment: @MichaelHall Say I have a mobile phone, some letters, and USB memory sticks within a sealed letter, with correct postage, addressed to solicitor and their office address. Is this subject to Legal Privilege even though I have not yet posted it?

Comment: Please give me some examples of things you strongly believe ARE subject to legal privilege, and offer a brief explanation why you think the examples you just mentioned might not be so that I can better understand your ongoing confusion and help you out.